What is the Galois group of a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$?
Suppose we have a degree-$n$ polynomial $p(X) \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$. How does one compute the Galois group of its splitting field, if that's tractable? My understanding so far:
First, we can without loss of generality take $p(X)$ to be separable; the splitting field doesn't change if we remove multiple roots.
Now let me look at the special case where $p(X)$ is irreducible, because I think I understand that case. The splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $p(X)$ in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. But it's a theorem that finite field extensions are Galois. In particular, $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1)$ already contains all the Galois conjugates of $\alpha_1$. Therefore (since $p(X)$ is irreducible and hence the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$),
$$\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) = \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(p(X))  \cong {\mathbb{F}}_{p^n}.$$
Therefore, the Galois group of the splitting field of a degree-$n$ irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
Question 1: Is the above all correct? If not, where did I go wrong?
Question 2: How do we generalize to the case of reducible polynomials? I know that the Galois group is always cyclic, but what's the order? My gut says that if $p(X) = \prod_{i=1}^m q_i(X)$ for irreducible $q_i(X)$, then the order is $\mathrm{lcm}(\mathrm{deg}(q_1(X)),\ldots,\mathrm{deg}(q_m(X)))$. Is that right? If not, what's a counterexample, and what's the correct answer?

That's correct, and your guess to question $2$ is correct as well. Try to prove it. Hint: If $L$ is the splitting field then $[L:\mathbb{F_q}]$ is the order of the Frobenius automorphism on $L$.
